# Dedicated server settings for Magento/large store

Tags: centos, magento

We have a dedicated server through fasthosts and are running 1 wordpress set up and a multi-store magento set up.

Our Magento sites are running at a slow speed back and front-end compared to the wordpress site.

Has anyone had experience of optimising a dedicated server for Magento?

I've posted our server spec below along with our configurations for php and my.cnf. We've followed some advice on tweaking the settings but things don't seem to be running any better.

As you can see we're not on a small server set up so we believe we should be getting better performance from it.

Can anyone see anything that we are doing wrong with the set up?

Server config

```
2x 2.1GHz AMD Opteron™ 12 Core processors
32GB RAM
2x 300GB SAS hard disk drives (RAID 1*)
2x 500GB SATA hard disk drives (RAID 1*)
Remote server control - keyboard, mouse & video control
Bandwidth & network
Unlimited bandwidth 100Mbps
99.99% network uptime guarantee
2 IP addresses - Additional IPs available
Create private LANs for your server - Option
Multiple UK internet connections
Flexible remote backup space - Option
Linux server operating system
CentOS 5.5
Ubuntu 10.04
Red Hat Enterprise Server v5.3
Apache web server
Courier mail server
Postfix mail transport agent
PureFTP FTP server
MySQL database management
Preconfigured IP Tables port security
Bind 9 DNS
```

my.cnf Settings:

```
[mysqld]
#set-variable=local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

key_buffer = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 16M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
tmp_table_size = 128M
thread_cache_size = 64
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 2M
max_connections = 500
wait_timeout = 300
thread_concurrency = 96
max_heap_table_size = 64M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12800M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 50
innodb_autoextend_increment = 8M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

php.ini settings

```
max_execution_time = 28000;
max_input_time = 60; 
memory_limit = 9216M;
```

Comment: how many stores are currently setup?

Comment: 1 base store and 12 stores from that although there is no product on the majority of them at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the issue with magento and multiple stores from what I found.

Magento does not scale with multiple stores. I was at a ecommerce startup that tried using magento to give bloggers shops. We used magento's multi-store of course. So the issue is each item that gets added to a store gets added to all the stores. Magento's DB model is good for making it very flexible but doesn't scale well when you have multiple stores. We had around 100 stores at the time with 5x the server power of you and adding a single product took 90 seconds.

This caused all sorts of things to be slow like checkout. So yes your server configs are ok and all but it's a magento problem.

We looked at queries that were run and some of them were 9 pages long for checkout and to add a product.

Sorry I don't have much help.. but my advice is to dump magento asap and find another solution.